# Is there an easy way to get the elements intersection between a couple of Flux objects using Project Reactor (Java/Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-reactor

I'm using Project Reactor with Spring boot in Java. I would like to know  if there is an easy way to get the elements intersection between a couple of Flux objects using Project Reactor without blocking.

Thank you!

Comment: if those are not infinite streams (or very large), you can collect all elements into a `Mono<List<Type>>` then zip the collections together. You will get couple of list. After that you can find those elements in the strandard way

Comment: @zlaval I think you misunderstood the intersection concept.I need to get the common elements between two groups of elements (2 Flux). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: No, flux is a stream, you have two flux for example. So you have to create 2 mono list from flux to find the elements.